# what different between int &p= n; int *q = &n;?

Tags: c++, pointers

1)what different between int &p= n and int *q = &n in this code they do same thing.
2)what do & exactly(maybe return addres variable or something different?)

```
    void foo(int &p){
        p++;
    }
    int main(){
    
        int n = 5;
    
    
        foo(n);
    
        int &p= n;
        int *q = &n;
    
        cout << *q;
        cout << p;
}
```

Comment: `p` is a reference, `q` is a pointer. What `&` does exactly would take a very long time to explain. If you want to learn C++ properly you need a [good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Answer (score 1):

> int &p= n;

`p` here is a (non-const) `int` *reference*, that refer to the object of type `int` with an associated named `n`. See [Reference declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference) for details.

> int *q = &n;

`q` here is an (non-const) pointer to an (non-const) `int` object, where the *address* of variable `n` is used to initialize the pointer; specifically by using the [address-of operator `&`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator) (`&expr`). The [Pointer declaration](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/pointer) for details.

Answer (score 0):

> 1)what different between int &p= n and int *q = &n

`p` is an lvalue reference to an object and `q` is a pointer to an object.

Some of the differences between references and pointers:

- References cannot be made to refer to other objects; Pointers can be re-assigned to point to another object.
- Pointers can point to null. A reference cannot refer to null.
- Indirection through a reference is implicit, while indirection through a pointer requires the use of the indirection operator.

> 2)what do & exactly(maybe return addres variable?)

In a compound type name, `&` means that the type is a reference. In an expression, the unary operator `&` is the addressof operator.